# Create new Instance of an Object in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, magento2

im cofusing how to create a new instance of an object in ZF2.
My class is called Clientela and i want to create a new instance of this class in another page, but im getting an error trying to do this.

My class is:

```
<?php 

namespace Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Clientela;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;

class Clientela{

private $id;
private $nome;
private $email;

public function __construct(){
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getNome(){
    return $this->nome;
}

public function setNome($nome){
    $this->nome = $nome;
}

public function getEmail(){
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email){
    $this->email = $email;
}
}


?>
```

and im trying to initialize in another page .php

```
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Clientela as Cli;

$cli = new Cli();
```

But its not working.
Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Clientela' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml on line 20
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you trying to create a instance of `Cli` inside your view?

Comment: Yes, just for understand.

Comment: Try `use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Clientela\Clientela  as Cli;`. The way you create an object instance in ZF is no different to PHP.

Comment: Do i have to map this class? Its still not working.

Answer (score 1):

It works after i set a "\" after all:

Page A:

```
 $cliente = new \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Clientela\Clientela(1,"raulzito","soares@example.com");
```

Class:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Clientela;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;

class Clientela {

private $id;
private $nome;
private $email;

public function __construct($id,$nome,$email){
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->nome = $nome;
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function setId($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getNome(){
    return $this->nome;
}

public function setNome($nome){
    $this->nome = $nome;
}

public function getEmail(){
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email){
    $this->email = $email;
}

}

?>
```